# handling nulls in a csv file using spark dataframe in scala (StructType)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I am trying to load a csv file into a dataframe with my own defined schema.
All i need is to identify bad data while loading it as a dataframe.

Bad data in my sense is

1. input contains String when schema tells Integer
2. unexpected/bad delimiter
3. any column data appearing as below, when my schema says nullable => false

   1. null
   2. ''
   3. //nothing

I am using a extra column "_corrupt_record" column to redirect records with  above 3 scenarios.

I could see this extra column getting populated during case 1) and case 2)
But when data is having Null (case 3.3), the record is not redirecting into this extra column. Its is working for 3.1 and 3.2.

Where am i doing wrong?

you can suggest me any other way that you use in realtime projects to handle/redirect bad data into a file while loading raw files into dataframes.

input file Products.txt 
schema : Product (product_id, product_name, product_type, product_version, product_price)

code:

```
val spark= new sql.SparkSession.Builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

val products_schema= StructType(List
  (
  StructField("product_id",IntegerType,false),
  StructField("product_name",StringType,false),
  StructField("product_type",StringType,true),
  StructField("product_version",StringType,true),
  StructField("product_price",StringType,true),
  StructField("_corrupt_record",StringType,true)
  )
)
val products_Staging_df=spark.read.option("header", false).option("delimiter", "|").schema(products_schema).csv("C:\\Users\\u6062310\\Desktop\\DBS\\Product.txt")


products_Staging_df.printSchema()
products_Staging_df.show()`
```

i put some bad records, when i use df.show()
i expected the records with product_id =  to also come under _corrupt_record column. but its not coming.

Only Null and '' were working correctly. How to handle blank?

Comment: I can give directions in Pyspark

Comment: your but its not coming. means  === DF.Show throwing error ? what it is saying ?

Comment: what is your sample input and what you want as output ?